Three JS, MindAR having issues casting a shadow from a GLTF
Ive tried traversing the GLTF and enabling shadows and also spawning in a plane for the shadow to be cast on.
Am new to AR with MindAR so am not sure if am missing something, possibly with the position of the directional light ? but Ive also tried a spotlight and no matter what I cant get a shadow to appear.
please bear in mind I am using image tracking in MindAR.
below is my code
import {GLTFLoader} from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { MindARThree } from 'mindar-image-three';


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , () => {
    const start = async () => {
    const mindarThree = new window.MINDAR.IMAGE.MindARThree({
        container: document.body,
        imageTargetSrc: '../../assets/targets/AR_MentalHealth.mind',
        uiScanning: "#scanning",
        uiLoading: "no",
    });
    
//renderer
    const {renderer, scene, camera} =mindarThree;
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    
    const anchor = mindarThree.addAnchor(0);
//switch camera
    document.querySelector("#switch").addEventListener("click", () => {
      mindarThree.switchCamera();
    });

//DirectionalLight
    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    directionalLight.position.set(200, 500, 600);
    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    directionalLight.shadow.radius = 2;
    directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
    directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 4000000;
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    
//plane
    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5,5);
    const planeMat = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
    planeMat.opacity = 0.5;
    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    plane.rotation.x = 0 * Math.PI;
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(plane);
    
    
//GLTFLoader
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load("../../assets/models/coffee/scene.gltf" , (gltf) => {
        gltf.scene.scale.set(0.4, 0.4, 0.4);
        gltf.scene.position.set(0, 0, 0.5);
        gltf.scene.rotation.set(1.55, 0, 0);
        gltf.receiveShadow = true;
        
        gltf.scene.traverse(function(node){
            if(node.isMesh)
                node.castShadow = true;
                node.receiveShadow = true;
        });
        
        anchor.group.add(gltf.scene);
        anchor.group.add(plane);
    });

    await mindarThree.start();
    renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    });
    }
    start();
});

I have tried a spotlight and I have also tried to traverse the GLTF, I know the plane is spawing in as I can see when I switch the material to a standard material.
